# PHP : ternary operator

Tags: php, wordpress

This seems like a very simple question but everything I try, gives me an error.

```
    if ( $query_results->have_posts() ) :   
    $count_results = $query_results->found_posts;
```

**Question: How to add `else` statement/functionality to this code?**

I've tried to add parentheses & `else`, I've also tried all combinations with `:` and `?`. Nothing works..

Comment: What do you want? And what is your question?

Comment: `($query_results->have_posts()) ?  $count_results = $query_results->found_posts; : 'ERROR';` ?

Comment: See the manual, http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php, `else:`. If you've already tried that show what you tried and what issue your encountered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not a ternary operator; it's [an uncommon `if` block syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php). Try this:

```
if ( $query_results->have_posts() ) {
    $count_results = $query_results->found_posts;
} else {
    // whatever
}
```

Note: there will be an `endif;` later in your code, which you also need to replace using the above syntax. There may also be `elseif (...):` or `else :` statements. While these are acceptable and work, they are generally considered more difficult to read, and you are better off using braces, as in my example above.

For what it's worth, the only project I have ever seen use the colon syntax (`if (...):`) is Wordpress. I'm sure they had a reason for doing so, but it's definitely the less common syntax.

Comment: Already tried it. `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE)`

Comment: @AWA odds are there's a block like `else :` further down in your code that you haven't posted; you'll have to change it, too.

Answer (score 3):

You're not using the ternary operator correctly.  Try:

```
$count_results = ($query_results->have_posts())? $query_results->found_posts : "YOUR ELSE EXPRESSION" ;
```